# how to create a web server into an android device ( for remote access)

Tags: android, web

How can I create a web server into my android device? I want to be able to access files on my sdcard android through my pc by entering the ip address on the browser.

Comment: i am also having the same  problem, please tell me what you did ...

Answer (score 2):

There are many applications already in existence to accomplish this task. If you wish to create your own app, [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) should integrate perfectly fine into your application using its embedded approach.

Answer (score 0):

Install and launch 'KSWEB' on your Android device. The app only has a six-day free trial, . There are a number of other web server apps, including Bit Web and Servers Ultimate.
 Navigate to the IP address listed by KSWEB in your  localhost:8080 on the Android device itself. After this you can easily manage access yourfiles using web server.